# Regular expression for floats with a fixed number of significant digits

Tags: regex, significant-digits

I'm trying to find a regular expression for a float with a fixed maximum (for example 4) number of significant figures.

this should match with:

```
- 123.4
- 12.34
- 1.2
- 223
- 0.1234
- 0.000001234
```

the problem is that the number of non-zeros before and after the dot has to be at most 4 in total.

I tried to split the problem and found solutions for the cases:

```
- 0.xxxx
- 0.000xxx
- xxxx
```

But I didn't find a solution for the case that significant digits are found before and after the dot. (`examples: 1.23  2.345` )

---

update: 
I think I found a solution:

```
^(?!(?:.*[1-9](\.?[0-9]){4,}))([-+]?\d+\.?\d*?)$
```

Comment: is `- ` a part of the input? is dot a necessary one?

Comment: - is not part of the input
. is not necessary

Comment: did you want to allow `.23` or `65.`?

Comment: yes, i allow .23 and 65. if that makes the problem more easy.

Comment: `/([1-9]+([0-9]+)?)?\.(([1-9])|(0+[1-9]+))/g` will match all significant digits (not answering your question, specifically, just thought it might be helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:.*?[1-9]){5,})([-+]?\s*\d+\.?\d*?)$
```

Try this.This will match only 4 or less significant digits.Do not forget to put flags `g` and `m`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/28

Comment: thanks! this is not exactly what I need because for example 122.04 is also matched but has 5 significant digits. But the use of a negative lookahead is a good hint!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
^0*(?:[1-9]\d{0,3})?(?:\.0*(?:[1-9]\d{0,3})?)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sM4zG2/5)

Comment: ok! but 0000.0000000012340 is also matched but has 5 sign. digits

Comment: sorry i don't know what do you mean. did you want to allow `100000.00001`

Comment: sorry, i don't allow that number because after the first non-zero ([1-9],the first digit) more than 4 digits [0-9] are printed.